# Tinn-R 3.0.3.6 gives errror source(.trPaths[5], echo=TRUE, max.deparse.length=150)

Tags: r, editor, tinn-r

I'm using `Tinn-R 3.0.3.6` as editor for `R`. When I try multiple lines of code `Tinn-R` runs only few and then throws the line:

```
source(.trPaths[5], echo=TRUE, max.deparse.length=150)
```

I wonder how I can overcome this behavior of `Tinn-R`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.trPaths is provided by TinnRcom package (distributed with the Tinn-R setup) and it is dependent of the user and flavor of the operational system.

The purpose of this variable is to avoid sending long paths related to files, blocks, selections, contiguous lines, etc.

Below my results:

```
> .trPaths
[1] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp"                   
[2] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\search.txt"       
[3] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\objects.txt"      
[4] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\file.r"           
[5] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\selection.r"      
[6] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\block.r"          
[7] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\lines.r"          
[8] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\reformat-input.r" 
[9] "C:\\Users\\jcfaria\\AppData\\Roaming\\Tinn-R\\tmp\\reformat-output.r"
```